# Connecting two individual long/lat points using CartoDB?

Tags: carto, latitude-longitude

I've created maps using CartoDB before, but my newest project is a little more advanced.

I've imported a dataset of tornado tracks on a particular day using Storm Prediction Center data. --> http://www.spc.noaa.gov/gis/svrgis/

What I've accomplished so far is showing the tornado touchdown points from the lat/long columns (see attached photo).

The table also contains the liftoff points from two additional lat/long columns. The problem is, I cannot seem how to display both points on the map and connect them by a line.

[image: Tornado points]

Comment: This tutorial is aimed at linking GPX track points, but may get you headed in the right direction: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/gps_track.html

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to create a new table with the same data and this time let cartodb geocode you lat/lng with the endpoints.

Then you have to create a visualization (if you not already created one).
Now you can make a line for two points with `ST_MakeLine`

Should look like this:

`SELECT 
  ST_MakeLine(
    the_geom_webmercator, 
    (SELECT 
      the_geom_webmercator
    FROM 
      your_table_with_endpoints_as_the_geom
    WHERE id = c.id LIMIT 1
    )
  ) AS the_geom_webmercator 
  FROM 
  your_table_with_startpoints_as_geom
    AS c`

if your tables have ids. or select something they have in common.

This blog post and video might help:
http://blog.cartodb.com/we-have-released-cartodb-2-1-enjoy-multilayer-maps-and/